# In Polymer 1.0 vulcanize + IE does not work for paper-drawer-panel

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use "vulcanize index1.html > index2.html", but am stumbling on an issue in IE. I have condensed it into this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html'>
</head>
<body>
<paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel">
    <div drawer>
        drawer
    </div>
    <div main>
        main
    </div>
</paper-drawer-panel>
</body>
```

In Chrome the result is fine, but in IE, "drawer" and "main" are shown incorrectly

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug which is already logged

https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize/issues/209